# Firebase Hosting Needs Re-verification

Tags: firebase-hosting

Since my hosting setup was done and working perfect, i got an mail about to re-verify my existing domain.

So when i check my setup, everything seems to be good, so i dont what to change or do.

My site is live at he moment and dont want to corrupt anything bu deleting my domains to re-verify.

[re-verify firebase hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frp5j.png)
Looking forward to hear if anyone had this before.

I only figured that, the TXT value firebase provided is not case-sensitive on my DNS Provider setup. would it be the case ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you remove the google-site-verification file after you initially validated you site(s)?

Comment: @Peter you mean do i removed the txt entry ? if so, no i didnt remove anything. everything still same as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i just figured that i have given dns rights to yandex, so that i have to configure yandex dns for firbase.

this is fixed now!

Comment: Hi! I crushed into the same error. What did you do? I don't understand what you meant.